# Sql Query to Linq using IN

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a `Sql Query` like :

```
select distinct FROM_EMAILID,FROM_COUNTRY from SURVEY_VISITORS
where FROM_COUNTRY IN 
(
  select top 1 FROM_COUNTRY as FROM_COUNTRY from SURVEY_VISITORS 
  where FROM_COUNTRY<>'undefined' 
  group by FROM_COUNTRY order by COUNT(*) desc
)
```

I'm unable to handle with `IN` Operator.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For the sub-Query,I've tried this way :

```
var innerQuery = (from t in VDC.SURVEY_VISITORS
                           group t by new
                           {
                              t.FROM_COUNTRY
                           } into g
                           orderby
                            g.Count() descending
                           select new
                           {
                             VisitorCount = (Int64?)g.Count(),
                             Country = g.Key.FROM_COUNTRY
                           }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I got the Result :)

var result = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_VISITORS
                                  where innerQuery.Country.Contains(xx.FROM_COUNTRY)
                                  select new
                                      {
                                          xx.FROM_COUNTRY,
                                          xx.FROM_EMAILID
                                      }).Distinct().ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var innerQuery = (from t in VDC.SURVEY_VISITORS
                  group t by new
                  {
                    t.FROM_COUNTRY
                  } into g
                  orderby
                  g.Count() descending
                  select new
                  {
                    VisitorCount = (Int64?)g.Count(),
                    Country = g.Key.FROM_COUNTRY
                  }).FirstOrDefault();

var result = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_VISITORS
                                  where ((innerQuery.Country.Contains(xx.FROM_COUNTRY)) && xx.TEMPLATE_ID == RecentBlastedTemplate.TEMPLATE_ID)                                  
                                  select new
                                      {
                                          xx.FROM_COUNTRY,
                                          xx.FROM_EMAILID
                                      }).Distinct().ToList();
```